# Quickest way to achieve this sequence?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to create a simple algorithm that builds an array with a dynamic length.

Then, it will, one by one, replace an item, and then two, then three and so on until the only items left are the first and last.

like this:

```
12345

1*345 // it never touches the first
12*45
123*5 // it doesn't ever touch the last item

1**45
12**5

1***5 // done, nowhere else to go
```

I put together a simple demo to show what I'm trying to do.

```
var length = 6,
    array = [],
    log = document.getElementById("log"),
    edited,
    j,
    i;

for (i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
    array.push(i);
}

log.innerHTML += array.join(" ") + "<br><br>";

for (i = 1; i < (length - 1); i++) {
    edited = array.concat();
    for (j = i; j < (length - 1); j++) {
        edited[j] = "*";
        log.innerHTML += edited.join(" ") + "<br>";
    }
    log.innerHTML += "<br>";
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qh9xmL6c/2/)

It works fine, the only problem is it's out of order.
Right now it seems to only iterate by number of asterisks, then by index. I need it to do the opposite.

```
// it does this
12345

1*345
1**45
1***5

12*45
12**5

123*5 // out of order
```

If someone could help that would be great because I am really at a loss!

Comment: It would certainly help to give your identifiers meaningful names.

Comment: When writing code, make sure to use useful variable names. If you have to write a comment on each line to explain what it means then it's probably because your naming is bad.

Comment: It looks like it's a failed minify attempt.

Comment: Here you go guys, I fixed up the variable names. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qh9xmL6c/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work well:

```js
str = "1234567"

len = str.length;

for(var stars = 1; stars < len - 1; stars++) {
  for(var pos = 1; pos < len - stars; pos++) {
    var s = str.substr(0, pos) 
      + new Array(stars + 1).join("*") 
      + str.substr(pos + stars);
    document.write(s + "<br>");
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you. simple, elegant, just what i needed. will accept when time is up.

Comment: @HavenLivell I would recommend against using document.write as it clears your entire webpage. You can see this by opening your console and typing `document.write('')`

Answer (score 1):

This should get it done.

```
var a = 6, // array length
    b = [], // array
    log = document.getElementById("log"),
    c,
    d,
    e;

for (c = 1; c <= a; c++) {
    b.push(c);
}

log.innerHTML += b.join(" ") + "<br><br>";

//the size of the asterisk chunk
for(i = 1; i < b.length - 1; i ++)
{
    //position to start asterisk chunk
    for(j = 1; j < b.length - i; j ++)
    {
        var tempArr = b.concat();

        //the position inside of the asterisk chunk
        for(k = 0; k < i; k ++)
        {
            tempArr[k + j] = "*";
        }

        log.innerHTML += tempArr.join(" ") + "<br>";
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qh9xmL6c/3/)